# reading editted text files scanner java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to read a text file into a scanner object.

```
    Scanner filescan = new Scanner (new File("src/specFiles/lists/Names"));
```

This code works fine, however I made manual changes to the text file. I made this list bigger. However those extra lines are not being read. It seems that the old file is still being read despite new saved changes. Any thoughts?

Comment: You've edited a different file than the one read by the Scanner. So this question can be closed.

Comment: Re-read the file. What actually happens when you create your scanner and read from it is platform dependent. It is a text file, that you manually edit. Check the time it was last modified, and if that is more recent, reload all of the data.

Comment: You should  also post the code using the scanner in order we know how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file location you are reading and update the correct one...

```
File f = new File("src/specFiles/lists/Names");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

This will print the exact location of the file read by Scanner...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, resources will be read from /target. If you update a resource you will need to run `mvn package` to update the resource in /target.